# How to derive the formula@NathanReed answer

Tags: mathematics

Thanks! A very simple but great way to estimate mean curvatures@NathanReed answer.
For my case, I also need an estimate of triangular mesh curvature, and I support this is what i was looking for.
However, could you please show me (or any recommended literature) how is the following equation derived?

$$\frac{(n_1 - n_0).(p_1 - p_0)}{||p_1 - p_0||^2}$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to CGSE. It's difficult to infer the context of your question when it is just referring to someone's answer. Could you please quote and/or link the relevant discussion in your question?

Comment: please kindly click this link:  https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-compute-principal-curvature-for-a-mesh-triangle/1719#1719?newreg=1059615fd16d40dcbcbc73980ae075de

Comment: I've extended my original answer with more explanation about the derivation of the formula. I think this question can be closed.