# Question about simple estimation of the discrete curvature at vertices of a mesh

Tags: mesh

In [this post](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-compute-principal-curvature-for-a-mesh-triangle/9344?noredirect=1#comment14162_9344), Nathan-Reed gave a simple, neat, "heuristic" estimation for the discrete curvature at vertices of a mesh.

In a nutshell, it computes a curvature *along* each edge incident to the vertex, then takes the geometric mean for the curvature in the vertex.

My question is: why is it better to take the geometric mean, instead of the arithmetic mean?

Is it because that would resemble somewhat Gaussian curvature?